# How to access Kubernetes cluster from my local windows machine

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes. I have created K8s cluster on my VM's which are VMware VM's. I have created helm charts to deploy my application. I want to install my application without logging into any of the cluster machines. Want to install it from my local windows 10 machine. How to configure my local machine to communicate with the Cluster? I have installed kubectl on my machine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the `kubeconfig` file into your local machine. In the master VM the file is saved at `$HOME/.kube/config`. Copy that into your `$HOME/.kube/config`. Then run `kubectl get nodes` to check connectoin

Comment: How to add the local machine to the set of allowed machines in kube config?

Comment: @SaketDeshpande would consider [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and accepting the answer if it  solved your problem?